# Swift Array Resetting Itself

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have two arrays: `pointHistory` and `dateHistory`. I also have an `NSTimer`, and when the timer runs out, its action is called. In that action I am appending an `Int` to `pointHistory`, and the current date as a `string` to `dateHistory`. Here is the timer action:

```
 func timerAction() {
    let stepperValue = Int(stepper.value)
    employee.numberOfPoints = stepperValue

    networking.saveEmployee(employee, completion: { (error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There was an error updating \(self.employee.name)'s points", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(alertAction)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

    var date = NSDate()
    var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

    //APPENDING HERE
    self.pointHistory.append(self.employee.numberOfPoints)
    self.dateHistory.append(dateString)
}
```

However, when the view loads up, these two arrays reset themselves back to being empty. Here is my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.title = employee.name


    editBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Edit, target: self, action: Selector("edit"))
    if let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 18) {
        editBarButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editBarButtonItem

    if let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 17) {
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    self.addScrollView()
    self.addProfilePicture()
    self.addUIElements()
    self.addLineChart()

    setChart(dateHistory, yVals: pointHistory)

}
```

The whole point of a dateHistory and a pointHistory is for me to add a line chart to my app, and all of the data is stored in these arrays. This is lao why you see a setChart function. For the lineChart, I am using an iOS Charts framework. Here is the actual body of the setChart function, as this is called in the viewDidLoad:

```
 func setChart(xVals: [String], yVals: [Int]) {
    var dataEntries = [ChartDataEntry]()

    for i in 0..<xVals.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: Double(yVals[i]), xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Number of Points")
    let lineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: xVals, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
    lineChart.data = lineChartData
}
```

Finally, just to supply more information, the cause of the arrays being reset could be because I implemented the viewWillAppear function. Here it is:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.refreshView()
}
```

Here is the `refreshView` function:

```
 func refreshView() {
    self.networking.findEmployeeForLoggedInUser { (array, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(alertAction)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.nameLabel.text = self.employee.name
                self.title = self.employee.name
                self.roleLabel.text = self.employee.jobDesc
                self.educationLabel.text = self.employee.education
                self.birthdayLabel.text = self.employee.birthday
                self.commentaryTextView.text = self.employee.commentary
                self.emailTextView.text = self.employee.email
            })
        }
    }

    self.networking.fetchImageForEmployee(employee, completion: { (error, image) -> Void in
        self.imageActInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White
        self.image.addSubview(self.imageActInd)

        self.imageActInd.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.imageActInd, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.image, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.imageActInd, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.image, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

        self.imageActInd.startAnimating()
        self.image.alpha = 0.5

        if error != nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.imageActInd.stopAnimating()
                self.image.alpha = 1.0
            })

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "\(error!)", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(alertAction)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.imageActInd.stopAnimating()
                self.image.alpha = 1.0
                self.image.image = image
            })
        }
    })
}
```

I don't know why these arrays are being reset to being empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where you have initialize array's

Comment: The arrays are global variables, so within the class itself. var pointHistory = [Int]() and var dateHistory = [String]()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This assumes that this all this code is running inside a single `UIViewController` instance.]

I think you misunderstand some aspects of the `UIViewController` lifecycle. `viewDidLoad()` is called only *once*, during your App's startup sequence, when none of the UI is visible, no components have been laid out, and no timers have been given a chance to start. Unless you're loading data in from a persistent store (disk; database; etc.) at this point, your arrays will have the values set from your overriding constructor (if you have one) or otherwise will have the values set from their class-level declaration initializers.

When do you start your `NSTimer`, and when do you expect it to go off?

Are you using `println()`s or debugging breakpoints to teach yourself the true sequence of events?

I also have to add that you're doing some UI code off the main thread, which is a big no-no. The presentation of your alerts must follow the same `dispatch` pattern as your non-error UI paths.

Comment: Here is where I start my NSTimer: I have a UIStepper, and every time its action is called, it reinitializes the timer until it runs out. Then the timerAction is called where I append to my arrays.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I check if there is any error, does that have to be under the same dispatch as my other UI paths?

Comment: @RehaanAdvani The same dispatch object (block) is not necessary. The principle here is a requirement to send any UI-related activities in *a* dispatch to the right thread.